# Does SSAS uses NTLM instead of Kerberos by default?

Tags: sql-server, security, ssas, kerberos

According to MSDN, [Unlike the SQL Server database engine, Analysis Services never auto-registers its SPN at service startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194200(v=sql.110).aspx). So, by default, there is no SPN (Service Principle Name) for SSAS instance.
If I understand Kerberos mechanics correctly, service cannot exist inside Kerberos realm without SPN.
Does it mean that by default, SSAS doesn't use Kerberos? Does it mean that SSAS uses outdated NTLM instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is configured that way, yes. Kerberos strictly requires a SPN. I guess SSAS uses SPNEGO which means that Kerberos fails and NTLM is selected.